# How to create temporary intermediate objects to pass to next method in Stream

Tags: java, constructor, java-stream, anonymous-class

I was continuing my book on Modern Java in Action where I got one more query.

In the Chap.-6 author is explaining about `groupingBy` where I can group list of transactions (`List<Transaction>`) by the `year` property of Transaction as follows

```
Map<Integer, List<Transaction>> txns = transactions.
                stream().
                collect(groupingBy(Transaction::getYear));
```

This `Transaction` class also have a member variable of Type `Trader (name, city)` (Please see the classes at bottom )

With this I am currently getting the transactions grouped by Year in the Map.

My Problem is : If I want to get the Trader name and value grouped by year, I think I have to create another intermediate class like below

```
Map<Integer, List<TraderWithValue>>  traderNamesWithAmountByYear = transactions.
                    stream().
                    map(ten -> createObjFromTxn(ten))
                    collect(groupingBy(Transaction::getYear));
```

So I want to check if there is a way by which I can avoid creating new class `TraderWithValue` which is used just one time. Like creating something on the fly like inline code ?

Below are my Transaction and Trader classes.

```
public class Transaction{
    private final Trader trader;
    private final int year;
    private final int value;
    // constructors, getters and setters
}

public class Trader{
    private final String name;
    private final String city;
    // constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to create a new class?

Comment: I am looking for more dynamic and inline kind of solution which can be applied in many places . I think if I start creating class there will be many value objects for different methods

Comment: The very first line of code you have shared is the way to do it if you want to avoid creating/using new classes. It would mean some more efforts to retrieve the data during reads but that is where you choose between a new representation versus making use of the existing one.

Comment: Hi @Naman, 

When I try creating new classes just for representing relationships b/w existing entities,  I feel like I am going far from the basic concepts of oops. or more precisely reviewers asks me questions that "what my class is referring to in real world ?"

In my particular case I feel like I am constrained somewhere by the java language barriers because some modern languages like javascript allows me to create objects on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Tuple<T, U>` for this if you're looking for dynamicity

However, you'll lose the comfort of having named variables.

A typical `Tuple<T, U>` for two variables is a `Pair<L, R>`

```java
public class Pair<L, R> {
    L left;
    R right;
}
```

---

You can use it like this

```java
Map<Integer, Tuple<String, Integer>> traderNamesWithAmountByYear =
    transactions.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Transaction::getYear,
                    Collectors.mapping(
                        tx -> new Tuple<>(tx.getTrader().getName(), tx.getValue()),
                        Collectors.toList()
                    )
                );
```

Comment: Thanks let me try

Comment: @NiteeshBhargava Do note, this would bring in a dependency on an additional library, or otherwise, you would end up defining another class. How do you read from the result could be a factor to decide upon how do you represent it, which the question lacks.

Comment: Agree @Naman, bringing the third party dependency is not a great idea when something can be done in our own source code.

\n<br/>However I didn't get this line clearly what exact detail my question lakes , would you mind explaining bit more ?\n<br/>

"How do you read from the result could be a factor to decide upon how do you represent it, which the question lacks."

Comment: In my case source can be anything like DB call/ API call or loading a transactions file from Local or Network drive.

Comment: A tuple is easy to implement in your code without dependency. It takes literally five minutes to code and test.